# This Delete statement in a MySql stored procedure does not work

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, elmah

I have this stored procedure to store errors in an Elmah table:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`b4d7eb33be6399`@`%` PROCEDURE `elmah_LogError`(
    IN ErrorId CHAR(36), 
    IN Application varchar(60), 
    IN Host VARCHAR(30), 
    IN Type VARCHAR(100), 
    IN Source VARCHAR(60), 
    IN Message VARCHAR(500), 
    IN User VARCHAR(50), 
    IN AllXml TEXT, 
    IN StatusCode INT(10), 
    IN TimeUtc DATETIME
)
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO `elmah_error` (
        `ErrorId`, 
        `Application`, 
        `Host`, 
        `Type`, 
        `Source`, 
        `Message`, 
        `User`, 
        `AllXml`, 
        `StatusCode`, 
        `TimeUtc`
    ) VALUES (
        ErrorId, 
        Application, 
        Host, 
        Type, 
        Source, 
        Message, 
        User, 
        AllXml, 
        StatusCode, 
        TimeUtc
    );

DELETE FROM `elmah_error` WHERE ErrorId NOT IN ( 
  SELECT ErrorId 
  FROM ( 
    SELECT ErrorId 
    FROM `elmah_error`
    ORDER BY TimeUtc DESC 
    LIMIT 100
  ) x 
);

END
```

I added the DELETE part to keep 100 last records only. The problem is that it does nothing. However, if I take this DELETE code alone and run it in a query window inside MySql Workbench, it correctly deletes records after the 100 I want to keep. Strange no?

Comment: not sure, but isn't `ErrorId` (for example) treathed as a variable into stored procedure scope? So DELETE statement will become `DELETE... WHERE 1244 NOT IN...` which is wrong. if you put them in backticks, will work. Same should be with TimeUtc

Answer (score 0):

Put backticks on column names:

```
DELETE FROM `elmah_error` WHERE `ErrorId` NOT IN ( 
  SELECT `ErrorId`
  FROM ( 
    SELECT `ErrorId` 
    FROM `elmah_error`
    ORDER BY `TimeUtc` DESC 
    LIMIT 100
  ) x 
);
```

Otherwhise they are threated as variables (because of same names) within procedure body.

Comment: Thanks. Added all the backticks. Still doesn't work.

Comment: What about putting `COMMIT` after each query?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I was trying to delete records older than x days (like every example out there). The problem was TimeUtc was also a parameter thus I needed to reference the table: WHERE `elmah_error`.`TimeUtc` < (NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH);

Probably the same issue with ErrorId.

Comment: Thanks. I did this and it changed nothing.